# IF functions and results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking to create a formula for 2 columns. The formula will check if the first column has a value greater than 1 and if the answer is yes it will then execute A1-B1 and show the answer. If the answer is no then it will be blank.

Answer (score 2):

In `C1`, you can use this formula:

```
=IF(A1>1,A1-B1,"")
```